# Java Fork-Join not working with large ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, parallel-processing, fork-join, forkjoinpool

I'm pretty new to parallelism and concurrency and I'm trying to implement a median filter algorithm using Fork-Join in Java. Basically I read an input file into an ArrayList and use that list to generate a new ArrayList of the filtered medians(including the first and last element of the original ArrayList).

Now I managed to make a Serial/Sequential version of the algorithm and it works fine. However when I tried to make a Fork-Join version, it does not seem to work for large ArrayLists(100000+). I tried it with a very small ArrayList of size 5 and it works fine. I cannot seem to be able to find my error(which I'm sure is a logic error and/or implementation error). Any help would be appreciated.

**Here's the sequential algorithm snippet:**

```
    //Add first boundary element to output ArrayList
    outputElements.add(this.elements.get(0));

    //Start Filter Algorithm 
    while(elements.size()-counter >= filterSize){
        for(int i = 0; i<filterSize; i++){
            tempElements.add(this.elements.get(i+counter));
            if(i==filterSize){
                break;
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(tempElements);
        outputElements.add(tempElements.get((filterSize-1)/2));

        counter++;
        tempElements.clear();
    }

    //Add last boundary element to output ArrayList.
    if (elements != null && !elements.isEmpty()) {
        outputElements.add(elements.get(elements.size()-1));
    }//End Filter Algorithm
```

**Here's the Parallel Class I made. This is the part that's not working:**

```
public class Parallel extends RecursiveTask<List<Float>>{
    int lo;
    int hi;
    int filterSize;
    String outFile; //Output file name.
    int arraySize;
    List<Float> elements = new ArrayList<Float>();
    List<Float> tempElements = new ArrayList<Float>();
    List<Float> outputElements = new ArrayList<Float>();
    int counter = 0;
    static final int SEQUENTIAL_CUTOFF=1000;

    public Parallel(List<Float> elements, int filterSize, String outFile, int lo, int hi) {
        this.lo = lo;
        this.hi = hi;
        this.elements = elements;
        this.outFile = outFile;
        this.filterSize = filterSize;       
        if(lo == 0){
            outputElements.add(this.elements.get(0));
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected List<Float> compute() {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime(); //Algorithm starts here 
        if((hi-lo) < SEQUENTIAL_CUTOFF) {
            while(hi-counter >= filterSize){
                for(int i = lo; i<filterSize; i++){
                    tempElements.add(this.elements.get(i+counter));
                    if(i==filterSize){
                        break;
                    }
                }               
                Collections.sort(tempElements);
                outputElements.add(tempElements.get((filterSize-1)/2));
                counter++;
                tempElements.clear();
                return outputElements;
            }
          }else{              
              Parallel left = new Parallel(this.elements, this.filterSize, this.outFile, this.lo, ((this.lo + this.hi)/2));
              Parallel right = new Parallel(this.elements, this.filterSize, this.outFile, ((this.hi + this.lo)/2), this.hi);
              left.fork();

              List<Float> leftArr = new ArrayList<Float>();
              List<Float> rightArr = new ArrayList<Float>();

             rightArr =  right.compute();
             leftArr = left.join();

             List<Float> newList = new ArrayList<Float>();
             newList.addAll(leftArr);
             newList.addAll(rightArr);       

          }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();//Algorithm ends here.

        //Write elements to output file 
        PrintWriter writeOutput = null;
        try {
            writeOutput = new PrintWriter(this.outFile, "UTF-8");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writeOutput.println(outputElements.size());//Number of lines
        for(int i=0; i<outputElements.size();i++){
            writeOutput.println(i+1 + " " + outputElements.get(i)); //Each line is written
        }

        writeOutput.close(); //Close when output finished writing.
        System.out.println("Parallel complete");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any help is really appreciated. I can't get this right after spending a few hours and researching a lot around S.O and Google.

Edit: musical_coder suggested to post the errors I'm facing and here they are. It's a lot of errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:536)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportResult(ForkJoinTask.java:596)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:640)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.invoke(ForkJoinPool.java:1521)
    at main.main(main.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at Parallel.compute(Parallel.java:44)
    at Parallel.compute(Parallel.java:57)
    at Parallel.compute(Parallel.java:57)
    at Parallel.compute(Parallel.java:57)
    at Parallel.compute(Parallel.java:57)
    at Parallel.compute(Parallel.java:57)
    at Parallel.compute(Parallel.java:57)
    at Parallel.compute(Parallel.java:57)
    at Parallel.compute(Parallel.java:57)
    at Parallel.compute(Parallel.java:57)
    at Parallel.compute(Parallel.java:57)
    at Parallel.compute(Parallel.java:57)
    at Parallel.compute(Parallel.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(RecursiveTask.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:784)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(ForkJoinPool.java:646)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:398)
```

Comment: In general, please avoid the phrase "it's not working", since that really doesn't give us anything to help you with. Instead, describe the specific problems you're facing- is it crashing/getting caught in an infinite loop/something else?

Comment: @musical_coder Thanks. I posted the errors in the edit. I'm not sure if it's wise to post all the errors like this. Feel free to edit it :)

Comment: Great, that stack trace is helpful. It looks like a lot of errors, but in reality it's all caused by a single exception which crashed your program, specifically at `Parallel.compute(Parallel.java:44)`. Cause: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0` (i.e., you're trying to access an array element that doesn't exist). Unfortunately, don't have time at the moment for deeper analysis, but take a look at line 44 and see where you went wrong. You could also try setting a breakpoint there to see if you can spot anything weird while the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should avoid using `ArrayList`s in multi-threaded code, because it is not thread-safe:

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads access an `ArrayList` instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it *must* be synchronized externally.

I don't see anything in the snippets you posted that modifies lists concurrently, but I *do* see you passing off `this.elements` to child `Parallel` instances, meaning at a minimum you're doing something risky (sharing pointers to mutable, non-thread-safe objects between threads).

As a first pass, replace `this.elements = elements;` in your `Parallel` constructor with the following:

```
this.elements = Collections.unmodifiableList(elements);
```

By making the list [unmodifiable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-), you'll ensure that if your `Parallel` code tries to mutate the list, you'll get a clear error right at the failure point.  This doesn't prevent something else, outside `Parallel` from modifying the original `elements` list, but it's a quick, easy way to verify `Parallel` is behaving correctly.  If you get an `UnsupportedOperationException`, your `Parallel` class will need to be redesigned - you cannot modify an `ArrayList` concurrently.

If you *don't* get an `UnsupportedOperationException`, something else is modifying your list.  You'll need to find that and remove it.

---

Once you've figured out what's causing your list to be mutated concurrently, you can try to determine the best way forward.  Going through all the "right" ways to share data between threads is beyond what I can hope to cover in this answer, but here are some general rules of thumb:

- **Avoid mutable data structures** - design your `Parallel` class to only process data from immutable data structures, like [Guava's `ImmutableList`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained).  Immutable data structures are thread-safe by default.
- **Use thread-safe data structures** - for instance, [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) is a threadsafe way for multiple processes to read and write to the same data structure.  [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) is another commonly used class.  What you'll need very much depends on what you're trying to do, but those are good starting points.
- **Minimize the scope of your concurrent operations** - even with concurrent data structures, your general goal should be for each task to run in isolation, save for reading from a shared source and writing to a shared sink.  Do as much work as possible on objects that are only visible to one thread.
- **Synchronize** - I notice that `Parallel` writes to `outFile` without any explicit synchronization.  This is dangerous, and likely to introduce problems (either crashes, or worse data corruption).  Only one thread should ever be writing to a file at a time.  Do so either by having a dedicated file-writing thread, or by explicitly synchronizing your file-writing operations.